# A construction "of the" and the usage of "take a rest" + articles

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles

1)"This place is an opportunity to take a rest in THE uniqueness OF THE local nature where you can feel Russian hospitality."

2)"You will have an opportunity to take a rest in the uniqueness of the local nature enjoying Russian hospitality. (Can I write “where you can feel Russian hospitality” instead?)"

Can I write: "in the uniqueness of the local nature"?

Is number 1 not correct? What about the second version? Its meaning, grammar, articles, the usage "of" in a sense of belonging to something?

Thanks!

Comment: I have deleted all of the comments here because I think we got off on the wrong foot. First of all, [Be Nice!](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) Second of all, don't write comments in any language other than English. I know it's tough when you're still learning and short phrases in your native language to try to help explain your point are OK. @Ricky you need to dial it back. Anastasia, if you feel that someone isn't be constructive in the comments, please flag it for the mod team.

Comment: @SovereignSun I appreciate your attempt to help here, but in the future, please flag it for the moderators. If someone had flagged this before there were 15+ comments we might have been able to get things back on track.

Comment: It is just a poor sentence. "Can I write: "in the uniqueness of the local nature"? No, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these sound natural to a native English speaker. I know it is challenging to use a foreign language and I wish I could more specific about what to fix. However, may I suggest :

> In this place, you will have the opportunity to relax and recuperate, experience our unique natural landscape, and enjoy Russian hospitality and culture.